# Adding tensor to particular columns of a tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I wish to add a tensor 'b' at particular columns (provided by cols) of tensor 'a'.

So in the following example, I wish to add tensor 'b' to first and the last column of each element of the batch.

```
 b = tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([10., 10.], dtype=float32)
    
 a = tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
            array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
                    [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]],
                   [[10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],
                    [15., 16., 17., 18., 19.]]], dtype=float32)
    
 cols = tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 4], dtype=int32)
```

And my desired outcome will be

```
out = tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
            array([[[ 10.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  14.],
                    [ 15.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  19.]],
                   [[20., 11., 12., 13., 24.],
                    [25., 16., 17., 18., 29.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Can someone tell the most efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_add?version=nightly), since you "wish to add tensor 'b' to first and the last column of each element of the batch":

```
import tensorflow as tf

b = tf.constant([10., 10.], dtype=tf.float32)
  
a = tf.constant([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
                  [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]],
                  [[10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],
                  [15., 16., 17., 18., 19.]]], dtype=tf.float32)
cols = tf.constant([0, 4], dtype=tf.int32)

indices = tf.stack([tf.repeat(tf.range(tf.shape(a)[0]), tf.shape(a)[0]*tf.shape(cols)[0]), tf.tile(tf.repeat(tf.range(tf.shape(a)[0]), tf.shape(a)[0]), [tf.shape(a)[1]])], axis=1)
indices = tf.concat([indices, tf.expand_dims(tf.tile(cols, [tf.math.reduce_prod(tf.shape(a)[:2])]), axis=-1)], axis=1)
updates = tf.tile(b, [tf.math.reduce_prod(tf.shape(a)[:2])])

print(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(a, indices, updates))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[10.  1.  2.  3. 14.]
  [15.  6.  7.  8. 19.]]

 [[20. 11. 12. 13. 24.]
  [25. 16. 17. 18. 29.]]], shape=(2, 2, 5), dtype=float32)
```

**Update 1**:

Generic approach to add `b` in any columns:

```
import tensorflow as tf

b = tf.constant([10., 10.], dtype=tf.float32)
  
a = tf.constant([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
                  [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]],
                  [[10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],
                  [15., 16., 17., 18., 19.]]], dtype=tf.float32)

cols = tf.constant([0, 1, 4], dtype=tf.int32)
#cols = tf.constant([0, 1], dtype=tf.int32)
#cols = tf.constant([0], dtype=tf.int32)
#cols = tf.constant([0, 1, 3, 4], dtype=tf.int32)

indices = tf.stack([tf.repeat(tf.range(tf.shape(a)[0]), tf.shape(a)[0]*tf.shape(cols)[0]), 
                    tf.tile(tf.repeat(tf.range(tf.shape(a)[0]), tf.shape(cols)[0]), [tf.shape(a)[1]])], axis=1)

indices = tf.concat([indices, tf.expand_dims(tf.tile(cols, [tf.math.reduce_prod(tf.shape(a)[:2])]), axis=-1)], axis=1)
updates = tf.repeat([b[0]],  tf.shape(indices)[0])
print(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(a, indices, updates))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although above code worked for you because of the shapes in the particular example, otherwise it fails. Quick check: your 'updates' tensor is independent of shape of cols. So it should fail when I change cols.

Comment: just try your script by using cols = tf.constant([0, 1,4], dtype=tf.int32)

Comment: Ok, I see..will update answer.

Comment: There are corrections in tf.stack() command as well

Answer (score 0):

Just building upon @AloneTogether's answer.

```
b = tf.constant([10., 10.], dtype=tf.float32)
    
a = tf.constant([[[0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
                  [5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]],
                 [[10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],
                  [15., 16., 17., 18., 19.]]],dtype=tf.float32)

cols = tf.constant([0, 4], dtype=tf.int32)
        
indices = tf.stack([tf.tile(tf.repeat(tf.range(tf.shape(a)[0]), tf.shape(cols)[0]), [tf.shape(a)[1]]),tf.repeat(tf.range(tf.shape(b)[0]), tf.shape(a)[0] * tf.shape(cols)[0])], axis=1)
indices = tf.concat([indices, tf.expand_dims(tf.tile(cols, [tf.math.reduce_prod(tf.shape(a)[:2])]), axis=-1)], axis=1)
updates = tf.tile(b, [tf.shape(a[0]*tf.shape(cols[0]])
    
print(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(a, indices, updates))
    tf.Tensor(
    [[[10.  1.  2.  3. 14.]
      [15.  6.  7.  8. 19.]]
     [[20. 11. 12. 13. 24.]
      [25. 16. 17. 18. 29.]]], shape=(2, 2, 5), dtype=float32)
```